# How to configure portable python with pycharm community

Tags: python, pycharm

I've just started experimenting with the new pycharm community edition. I have a dev environment on a USB stick which includes portable python (http://portablepython.com). I would like to configure the editor to use this. I've installed portable python at:

```
F:/ppython27/Python-Portable.exe
```

When I try to configure this, the IDE does not seem to recognize the Python-Portable.exe and the entry in the Python interpreter window reads:

```
Unknown at F:/ppython27/Python-Portable.exe
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Since it is likely you are running it on windows, have you tried specify the path as "f:\\ppython27\\Python-Portable.exe"?

Comment: I am working on windows but "f:\\ppython27\\Python-Portable.exe" does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this has been solved already, but that is the wrong exe to look for. You need to find the "python.exe" executable as you would in a normal installation of python. With Pycharm though I doubt it will be 100% compatible with Portable Python. But it should mostly work once you do that.

Comment: Hi ArcadeJL , thanks for answering. There is no python.exe in the directory.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and also for not being that specific. This is the path on my USB. "E:\Enpyronment\Portable Python 3.2.5.1\App\python.exe" That's what you need to look for. If I'm not mistaken it should be the same or similar to the paths for v2.7

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your environment!

Answer (score 1):

Check the "[portable python](http://portablepython.com)" by [Perica Zivkovic](https://github.com/pericazivkovic/portablepython), it seems to have pycharm packed.

Have a peek into its patch and config files ----

- modules.bat

  ```
  :: Patch PyCharm
  call COMMON :LogMessage "Patch PyCharm"
  del %UNPACK_FOLDER%\PyCharm\App\PyCharm\bin\idea.properties /Q
  tools\uniextract16\UniExtract.exe "patches\PyCharm.3.1.x.PPpatch" "%UNPACK_FOLDER%\PyCharm\App\PyCharm" >NUL

  :: Replace @PY_VERSION@ in jdk.table.xml.tmp to %PY_VERSION% jdk.table.xml
  setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  set filein="%UNPACK_FOLDER%\PyCharm\App\PyCharm\.PyCharm30\config\options\jdk.table.xml.tmp"
  set fileout="%UNPACK_FOLDER%\PyCharm\App\PyCharm\.PyCharm30\config\options\jdk.table.xml"
  set old=@PY_VERSION@
  set new=%PY_VERSION%
  for /f "tokens=* delims=? %%i in ( '"type %filein%"') do (
      set str=%%i
      set str=!str:%old%=%new%!
      echo !str! >> %fileout% 
  )
  del %filein%
  ```
- jdk.table.xml (zipped into *PyCharm.3.1.x.PPpatch*)

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <application>
    <component name="ProjectJdkTable">
      <jdk version="2">
        <name value="Portable Python 2.7" />
        <type value="Python SDK" />
        <version value="Python 2.7" />
        <homePath value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../pythonw.exe" />
        <roots>
          <classPath>
            <root type="composite">
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/.." />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../DLLs" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/lib-tk" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/site-packages" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/site-packages/PIL" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/site-packages/gtk-2.0" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/site-packages/win32" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/site-packages/win32/lib" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/site-packages/pythonwin" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/../Lib/site-packages/wx-2.9.4-msw" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/helpers/pycharm" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/helpers/python-skeletons" />
              <root type="simple" url="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/.PyCharm30/system/python_stubs/580531057" />
            </root>
          </classPath>
          <sourcePath>
            <root type="composite" />
          </sourcePath>
        </roots>
        <additional>
          <PATHS_ADDED_BY_USER_ROOT PATH_ADDED_BY_USER="file://$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/helpers/pycharm" />
        </additional>
      </jdk>
    </component>
  </application>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I use PyCharm Portable in combination with WinPython and it works just fine.

https://portableapps.com/node/56602

https://winpython.github.io/